# creating frontend validations with materialize and Angular 4

Tags: angular, validation, frontend, materialize

Given I need to use one, should I focus on using Angular 4's front end validations or materialize css' validations knowing I will merge it with a Django backend framework?  Or does it matter?

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but I'm pretty sure it is the perfect spot but I've been tasked with starting the front end of a Django project that is using an Angular 4 front end.  So far, in the past, I have created mini assignments that required validation through materialize (that was just a simple exploration of using materialize on a very simple site), validation for an Angular 4 login example (again just for a simple exploration of the language), and am not familiar with Django validations but know those are the important ones in terms of saving a user properly.

Any preferences or danger zones I might run into using one or the other would be awesome!

thanks folks

Comment: Without knowing more about how you plan to use which pieces of which technologies, it will be difficult to provide guidance on where validation is best defined. I have not used Django, but Angular provides both template-driven forms and reactive forms, both with client-side validation features. I'm assuming that this question will be closed by the moderators as an answer would be too much "opinion",

Comment: ok.  that's what I was afraid of.  Really I just don't want to use one thing and have it make it impossible to incorporate with Django.  Having said that, I obviously need to do more research! thanks